# how to count and dcast for all columns in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
     Company     Education    Health      
        A           NA          1              
        A           1           2             
        A           1           NA
```

I want the count of levels in each columns(1,2,NA) in a following format

```
     Company     Education_1   Education_NA   Health_1    Health_2    Health_NA
       A            2             1             1            1            1
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: That seems like an awful output format for your data. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I just need the count of different levels in every columns. I can do it individually by geoupby and dcast. Is there any way to do it with shorter code?

Comment: Sure, take a look at my `tidyverse` solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(k, v, -Company) %>%
    unite(tmp, k, v, sep = "_") %>%
    count(Company, tmp) %>%
    spread(tmp, n)
## A tibble: 1 x 6
#  Company Education_1 Education_NA Health_1 Health_2 Health_NA
#  <fct>         <int>        <int>    <int>    <int>     <int>
#1 A                 2            1        1        1         1
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "     Company     Education    Health
        A           NA          1
        A           1           2
        A           1           NA         ", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `DF` in the Note at the end where we have added a company B as well and using the reshape2 package it can be done in one recast call.  The `id.var` and `fun` arguments can be omitted and the same answer will be given but it will produce a message saying it used those defaults.

```
library(reshape2)

recast(DF, Company ~ variable + value, 
  id.var = "Company", fun = length)
```

giving this data frame:

```
  Company Education_1 Education_NA Health_1 Health_2 Health_NA
1       A           2            1        1        1         1
2       B           2            1        1        1         1
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "  Company Education Health
1       A        NA      1
2       A         1      2
3       A         1     NA
4       B        NA      1
5       B         1      2
6       B         1     NA"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `plyr` you can use a hack with `ddply` by transposing tables to get what appear to be new columns:

```
x <- data.frame(Company="A",Education=c(NA,1,1),Health=c(1,2,NA))

library(plyr)
ddply(x,.(Company),plyr::summarise,
                       Education=t(table(addNA(Education))),
                       Health=t(table(addNA(Health)))
)
  Company Education.1 Education.NA Health.1 Health.2 Health.NA
1       A           2            1        1        1         1
```

However, they are not really columns, but table elements in the data.frame.

You can use a `do.call(data.frame,y)` construct to make them proper data frame columns, but you need more than one row for it to work.